# Performance in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance

If i have a Model named **User** with, let say 20 properties and i create a view model:

```
// The model
class User{
// 20 properties...
}

public UserViewModel : Models.User {
// now this class has all property of User model
// and i add a new property that i need 

public string Address{get;set;}// not bellowing to User Model but need it in view

}
```

And i send ony 2 request with the key of UserName, Address by ajax. And i do this to process the request

```
public JsonResult ProcessingRequest(UserViewModel userModel){
// doing some things here...
}
```

Since UserViewModel extends from User, then the request will try to cast all GET request's key that match with the Given model, including User. But im only using 2 properties, UserName and Address. There are 19 properties not being used.

So, **What would be the performance's impact while casting the request to that model?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you could tell the difference in performance with 20 properties or 2, anyway the best way to kill your doubt its to take a profiler and do a benchmark with 2 or 20 properties.

Anyway I believe your problem is that you dont need the information of the user, so there is no point on doing this view model like that, just create what you need and map it later at your need. Remember you can create different view models for Edit, add or custom actions as yours.

You can create a UserProcessingRequestViewModel with the fields you need and send it to the ProcessingRequest and It will just map it.

(This started as a comment but maybe was too much for there and added it here.)